# Mariadb case insensitive fulltext search on json columns

Tags: php, json, laravel, mariadb, case-insensitive

I am using laravel but can use raw sql if needed.

I have multiple fields that are json fields, in that json there is translated data for that language. So, for example post table has field title and that title is `{"en": "Title in english", "et": "Title in estonian"}`

Now I need to make a fulltext search that searches these fields, for some columns i need to search term from all languages, not just from active one.

I am using MariaDB latest stable.

If i make index of these fields for fulltext search i can search fine but the search is case sensitive.

How can i make the search case insensitive? The json fields are currently `longtext` and `utf8mb4_bin`, laravel chose them for json field. I know bin is case sensitive collation but what else could i put so the functionality to find records by translated slug (for example) would be still there.

In laravel, one can search like `->where('slug->en','some-post-slug')`. So i need to keep laravels json fields functionality intact.

I have been trying to achieve this for 2 days now, i need some external input.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL documentation [states the following](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> *By default, the search is performed in case-insensitive fashion. To perform a case-sensitive full-text search, use a case-sensitive or binary collation for the indexed columns. For example, a column that uses the utf8mb4 character set of can be assigned a collation of utf8mb4_0900_as_cs or utf8mb4_bin to make it case-sensitive for full-text searches.*

I bet it's the same in MariaDB. If you change your collation it will work with case-insensitive searches like expected. You can change it that way:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 
COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```